# How to Add 5 to each element of an array and replace the old elements with the new ones (after +5)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

See I wrote the code already, and this works for an array with heterogeneous elements (e.g. [2 3 4 5] (different elements), however, if the elements are homogenous (e.g. [2 5 5 8]), the output doesn't work as expected. How do I fix this?

code below:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 5])

print("arrray x is"+" "+str(x))

print()

i = 0

while i<(len(x)):

    z = (x[i]+5)

    print("The new value for x["+str(i)+"] is"+" "+str(z))

    j = 0

    while j<(len(x)):

        if (x[j]+5) == z:

            x = np.where(x==x[j], z, x)

        j += 1

    i+=1

print()

print("Now the array x is"+" "+str(x))
```

Comment: ...why not just try `x = x + 5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 5])

new_lst = x+5
print(new_lst)
```

OUTPUT `[6, 7, 8, 8, 10]`

Thanks, @matszwecja.

Comment: You don't even have to add a np.array, adding a scalar will work just the same.

Comment: @matszwecja Yeah.

Comment: by scalar I meant simply `x + 5`, but whatever, this works too.

Comment: @YunYoo Don't pick a random video from youtube Instead just pick a playlist of the full course.  I suggest seeing this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZIRAavoGng&list=PLjVLYmrlmjGcQfNj_SLlLV4Ytf39f8BF7)

Comment: @YunYoo This is simple code because it's a `numpy array` then you can simply use `x+5`, It simply adds 5 to every element inside the array.

Comment: @SharimIqbal I know that the code below is to specify a type of character for end user input, but i don't understand how the code works. Please help me understand. I cannot a post another question for 90 minutes so i posted here.

valid=False

while not valid:

    try:
        specify_array_len = int(input("Enter array length: "))

        valid = True

    except ValueError:

        print("Use an integer.")